# How to get a date in a link? MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm implementing a web page, doing the homepage, I have a button that the user uses in order to recover his password (due to forgetting it). Then my program sends him a link to his e-mail after verifying it in the database. This link let's the user reset his password.

I want to add a date to the link, so that if when the user gets redirected to the reset pass page, it's date is verified and if it is higher than 1 hour it tells the user he needs to re-do the process.

Do I use,

```
DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;?
```

Sorry for the bad English, thank you

Comment: Are you using something similar to SimpleMembership as you can readjust the default timeout?

Comment: You could handle this in the `DB` instead, save the date and time the user requested a reset, and then check against current time when they decide to action the reset.

Comment: Agree with @christiandev, this is the best option as using URL parameters can be bypassed by the user.

Comment: can I do like this:

    SELECT DATEDIFF(day, Today, Link_day) AS DiffDate

if(DiffDate >1)
select -1; -- the user gets a new page saying he needs to re-do his password retrieval
else
select 1; --Proceeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.Now.Ticks`. This gives you an integer that can easily be posted in an url and then be converted to a DateTime again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this doesn't quite answer your question, however there is a better way of handling password reset timeouts. If you are using the following code in your action:

```
WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(emailAddress);
```

You can also pass in a second parameter which specifies how long the password token is valid for in minutes otherwise the default time out is 24 hours.

From there you can validate the token is valid in a `bool` type action by using something similar to the below:

```
var repository = repository.GetByPasswordResetToken(resetToken);
isValid = membership != null && repository.PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate > DateTime.Now;
```

This is based on the assumption you are utilising WebMatrix within your server side logic.